# Avoid linebreak in empty html tags

Tags: html, css, r-markdown

Is it possible to avoid rendering a linebreak when html tags are empty ?

For example

```
---
output: html_document
---

::: {}
:::

<p></p>

<p>a</p>
```

The html rendered looks like this :

[image]

Instead of getting an empty tag such as `<div></div>` a linebreak is inserted, how to avoid it ?

It would be useful to detect if a div is empty or not for example. I'm creating dynamic documents and I would like to apply styles to empty div, using the `:empty` css pseudo element, and it's not considered as empty with the linebreak.